# What is Intellectual Anarchism?

Tags: political-philosophy, analytic-philosophy

Every now and then I hear the phrase "intellectual anarchism".  What does this mean exactly?  Wikipedia has no article of that name, and google doesn't throw up much (a few disparate uses of the phrase in different contexts - political, artistic, etc).

Comment: Not sure if it is the same but Feyerabend is characterized as epistemological anarchist sometimes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemological_anarchism.

Comment: I think this is the gap in my knowledge, thanks.  I guess when people say intellectual anarchist they either mean this, or a political theorist like Chomsky i.e. the intellectual end of the political anarchy spectrum.  Depending on context.

Comment: @SideshowBob if you want to explore Feyerabend a bit, I recently put together a [list of links](http://egtheory.wordpress.com/2014/09/26/feyerabend/) as introduction to his philosophy of science. Maybe you'll find it useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is basically an answer included by reference in the comments.  But I will lay it out for concreteness sake.

I would agree with @Conifold and @Artem... that the most likely reference is to someone like Feyerabend, though indirectly (via Kuhn's abstraction of 'paradigm') the position is Neitsche's notion of 'creation'.  So the same idea is widespread, if less clearly discerned elsewhere.

The basic point is that everyone wants to place limits on what can be considered legitimate argument, but that the arguments made for doing so generally aren't legitimate in their own terms, and surely do not meet one-another's standards.  They derive their power to ignore one another's standards sociologically, at some point, from the combined strength of personality of the actors drawn to them.

It is not 'post-modernism' outright, but a strong lean in that direction -- either one needs to judge modernism by its own standards or question all limitations that don't meet standards that are equally strong.

In Feyerabend's case, he is attacking the way in which theories of scientific evolution become prescriptive methods that allow us to write off earlier scientists as illegitimate even when they were correct, and Bowdlerizes the real thinking of those we canonize, by shoehorning them into a larger framework for our own intellectual comfort.  We then accept their answer, and pretend we would have gotten there by our accepted means.  But that weakens our collection of methods, forevermore (or at least until we lose the argument on methodology).

Neitsche is on the same path turning away from choosing bases for morality, as arbitrary, in favor of addressing the genealogy of moral sentiments in a way that recognizes how moral bases get refolded over time or reframed totally by powerful personalities, and thereby declares them all wrong (and destined to remain wrong).  That brings him back to simply considering morality personal.

Basically, faith in the correctness of human enterprise is human and not rational.  To pretend that we fully understand what it is to be human, or even rational, for all time is nonsense.  So we need to leave a lot of leeway for taste and arbitration in our judgments of social or intellectual works.